# Multiple Controllers in one view AngularJS + Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, controller

I'm coding a single crud application, and i need to use two controllers in one view, but i dont know how.

When the user press the "Add Colaborador" button, the application needs to search the "Função" registers, and show in a select(Html function). (One "Colaborador" have one "Funcao").

Here's my code:
http://pastebin.com/uUzE5K28

For use the , i need to change the controller to "funcoesController", then come back to "colaboradoresController".

Sorry for bad english!

Comment: Just create two controllers with `app.controller( ...`. then put `ng-controller` for each controller on any element of your view which you like to be controller scope boundary.

Comment: sorry, but i'm new using angularjs, and i don't know how to do that. Where do i put the app.controller?

Comment: Sounds like you need to go through some angular tutorials like https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Angular can nest controllers.  So you can embed one controller in another controller.  Within the nested controller, you can access either controller.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="registrosGerais">
    <head>
        <title>Sistema Pronatec</title>

        <!-- Load Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="<?= asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Gerenciamento de Colaboradores</h2>
        <div ng-controller="colaboradoresController">
            <!-- Nest second controller -->
            <div ng-controller="funcoesController">
                <button id="btn-add" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="toggle('add', 0)">Novo Colaborador</button>

            <!-- Table-to-load-the-data Part -->
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nome</th>          
                        <th>Função</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="clb in tbcolaborador">
                        <td>{{clb.id}} </td>
                        <td>{{ clb.nome }}</td>
                        <td>{{ clb.funcao_id}}</td>

                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-detail" ng-click="toggle('edit', clb.id)">Editar</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete"                                 ng-click="confirmDelete(clb.id)">Remover</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-detail"                                 ng-click="addConta(clb.id)">Adicionar Conta Banco</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{form_title}}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form name="frmColaboradores" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">

                                <div class="form-group error">
                                    <label for="inputNome" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nome</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control has-error" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome completo" value="{{nome}}" ng-model="colaborador.nome" ng-required="true">
                                        <span class="help-inline" ng-show="frmColaboradores.nome.$invalid && frmColaboradores.nome.$touched">Nome é obrigatório</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group error">
                                    <label for="inputFuncao" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Função</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <select>
                                            <option ng-repeat = "clb in tbfuncao" value "{{ clb.id }}"> {{ clb.nome }} </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  

                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"                                id="btn-save" ng-click="saveColaborador(modalstate, id)"                                ng-disabled="frmColaboradores.$invalid">Salvar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Load Javascript Libraries (AngularJS, JQuery, Bootstrap) -->
    <script src="<?= asset('app/lib/angular/angular.js') ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?= asset('js/jquery.min.js') ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?= asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') ?>"></script>

    <!-- AngularJS Application Scripts -->
    <script src="<?= asset('app/app.js') ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?= asset('app/controllers/colaboradores.js') ?>"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm gettin this error: angular.js:13550 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'funcoesController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=funcoesController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined     Here's the full code: http://pastebin.com/4jaAtNBx

Comment: You need to include the script library containing your controller in the view.  I assume it is <script src="<?= asset('app/controllers/funcoes.js') ?>"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You should not access two controllers from the same view. This kind of cross dependency will most likely drive you crazy when one change things in one controller and start noticing crashes in unexpected places.

Your Laravel controller can pass all needed data to your view, including the lookup data as an additional array variable. That's the simplest way.

Laravel has many different ways to pass additional data to your views. Besides direct variable references, you can create [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers) or inject service providers into your views with [Service Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#service-injection) (in Laravel 5.2). You would want to choose this kind of solutions if you need the same reference data in multiple places to keep the code DRY.